# Positive lookahead to capture IP in DNS record `* IN A 192.0.50.1`

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex to capture IP in a DNS record that looks like this:

```
* IN A 192.0.50.1
```

This is my attempt:

```
(?=\*\s+IN\s+\w\s+)(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)
```

I am using positive lookahead to say it has to start with "* IN A" but I actually want to capture as a group the IP address, not interested in anything else.

Comment: It should be `(?<=`, not `(?=` - see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/XkIWuW/1). Or just use a consuming pattern, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/XkIWuW/2).

Comment: Do you use Unix* tools?

Comment: No lookahead needed. Just use: `\*\s+IN\s+\w\s+((?:\d+\.){3}\d+)` and grab capture group #1

Comment: If you can use Perl: `perl -MRegexp::Common -lne 'print $1 if /($RE{net}{IPv4})/' file`